# moving the tables from one position to another with using css only

Tags: html, css

here i have two tables

```
<div class="ex1">
<table>
<th> table1</th>
<tr>..</tr>
<tr>....</tr>
</table>
</div>
<div class="ex2">

<table>
<th>table2</th>
<tr>..</tr>
<tr>....</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

my css for those class ,what i wrote is

```
.ex1{
display: block;
position: relative;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0px solid #CCC;
overflow: hidden;
clear: right;
height: 392px;
width: 630px;
}

.ex2{
display: block;
position: relative;
clear: right;
margin: 3px 0 0 0;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
padding-top: 0px;
color: #5A5655;
background-color: #F8F8F8;
text-align: left;
overflow: auto;
z-index: 88;
height: 50px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
width: 620x;
}
```

here what i want is when i wrote the above code ,it displays the 2 tables fine,i want to display the table2 first ,then i want to display the table1 by using css only without touching the html code....
how can i do this one ? can anyone help me...

Comment: HTML isn't really __code__, per se.

Comment: @WilliamVanRensselaer I think we can agree to disagree on that one... :)

Comment: Can you use JavaScript? It would be very easy (and preferable) to switch the two elements physically using JS.

Comment: You want to create table 1 from css?

Comment: @Tieson you probably mean HTML is not a *programming language*. It's still *code* though http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code

Comment: no,i want to display table2 first,then table1 by changing the css only

Comment: by using css, i want to change.is it possible?

Comment: @kanya not really, no. Not in a robust way. So you can't use JavaScript?

Comment: Wait, do you want `table2` on top of `table1`?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Y3BMe/

Use `position:absolute` for the second table with `top: 0` and then move down the first table by using the `margin-top` property

In your real world example it may require some tweaking - see [css positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp) for help